# Wikidata Sparql: how to access award point of time and work from a person

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I try to adapt a Freebase-based quiz generator to Wikidata since Freebase closed.
I have a lot of trouble doing so, for now I'm stuck with a simple problem:

How can I have the awards winning date and for starting from a person?

Example: I want to have `2016` and `The Revenant` for `Leonardo Dicaprio`.
I tried several requests like this one:

```
SELECT ?id ?idLabel ?date ?forWork
WHERE {
  wd:Q38111 wdt:P166 ?id .
  ?id wdt:P585 ?date .
  ?id wdt:1411 ?forWork .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "fr" }
}
```

The problem is that the point of date (`wdt:P58`) is linked to award received (`P166`), and not `Leonardo DiCaprio` nor `Academy Award for Best Actor`.

Those information are available on the [Leonardo DiCaprio page](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q38111) (as sub part of awards received)

Another problem I have is to access all data of `Leonardo` from his name as a string and not an id.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As all the data seems to be in the qualifiers, I came up with something like this:

```
SELECT ?actor ?actorLabel ?award ?awardLabel ?date ?forWork ?forWorkLabel
WHERE
{
  # find a human
  ?actor wdt:P31 wd:Q5 .
  # with English label "Leonardo DiCaprio"
  ?actor rdfs:label "Leonardo DiCaprio"@en .
  # Now comes the statements/qualifiers magic:
  # just applying what the documentation says https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service/queries#Working_with_qualifiers
  # using this query as example https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service/queries#US_presidents_and_their_spouses.2C_in_date_order
  ?actor p:P166 ?awardstatement .
  ?awardstatement ps:P166 ?award .
  ?awardstatement pq:P585 ?date .
  ?awardstatement pq:P1686 ?forWork .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en,fr" . }
}
```

You can [try it here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Factor%20%3FactorLabel%20%3Faward%20%3FawardLabel%20%3Fdate%20%3FforWork%20%3FforWorkLabel%0AWHERE%0A%7B%0A%20%20%23%20find%20a%20human%0A%20%20%3Factor%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ5%20.%0A%20%20%23%20with%20English%20label%20%22Leonardo%20DiCaprio%22%0A%20%20%3Factor%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%22Leonardo%20DiCaprio%22%40en%20.%0A%20%20%23%20Now%20comes%20the%20statements%2Fqualifiers%20magic%3A%0A%20%20%23%20just%20applying%20what%20the%20documentation%20says%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fwiki%2FWikidata%3ASPARQL_query_service%2Fqueries%23Working_with_qualifiers%0A%20%20%23%20using%20this%20query%20as%20example%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fwiki%2FWikidata%3ASPARQL_query_service%2Fqueries%23US_presidents_and_their_spouses.2C_in_date_order%0A%20%20%3Factor%20p%3AP166%20%3Fawardstatement%20.%0A%20%20%3Fawardstatement%20ps%3AP166%20%3Faward%20.%0A%20%20%3Fawardstatement%20pq%3AP585%20%3Fdate%20.%0A%20%20%3Fawardstatement%20pq%3AP1686%20%3FforWork%20.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%2Cfr%22%20.%20%7D%0A%7D%0A) and [get the data there](https://query.wikidata.org/sparql?format=json&query=SELECT%20%3Factor%20%3FactorLabel%20%3Faward%20%3FawardLabel%20%3Fdate%20%3FforWork%20%3FforWorkLabel%0AWHERE%0A%7B%0A%20%20%23%20find%20a%20human%0A%20%20%3Factor%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ5%20.%0A%20%20%23%20with%20English%20label%20%22Leonardo%20DiCaprio%22%0A%20%20%3Factor%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%22Leonardo%20DiCaprio%22%40en%20.%0A%20%20%23%20Now%20comes%20the%20statements%2Fqualifiers%20magic%3A%0A%20%20%23%20just%20applying%20what%20the%20documentation%20says%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fwiki%2FWikidata%3ASPARQL_query_service%2Fqueries%23Working_with_qualifiers%0A%20%20%23%20using%20this%20query%20as%20example%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fwiki%2FWikidata%3ASPARQL_query_service%2Fqueries%23US_presidents_and_their_spouses.2C_in_date_order%0A%20%20%3Factor%20p%3AP166%20%3Fawardstatement%20.%0A%20%20%3Fawardstatement%20ps%3AP166%20%3Faward%20.%0A%20%20%3Fawardstatement%20pq%3AP585%20%3Fdate%20.%0A%20%20%3Fawardstatement%20pq%3AP1686%20%3FforWork%20.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%2Cfr%22%20.%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A)

Comment: Thank you very much ! I actually miss the point with qualifiers (ps, pq, etc.) I will look for those documentations I think it should come handy for all I need to do !

Comment: For those looking for the documentation on qualifiers, there is a good [section on qualifiers](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_tutorial#Qualifiers) in the excellent [Wikidata:SPARQL tutorial](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_tutorial)